# When setting a background color on a button's style, it changes the margins

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-xml, android

If I set the background color, the margins between the buttons using this style are much smaller than without it. Why? How do I fix this?

```
<style name="RemoteButton">

    <!-- Leaving this in makes the buttons very close together, without it, the margins increase -->
    <item name="android:background">#d6d7d7</item>

    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#556699</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set android:includeFontPadding="false" because every font has its own custom padding associated with it. Check and reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default button style is not a color, it's a drawable resource (`@android:drawable/btn_default`) with internal padding/margins. There is some information on it [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default.xml) but not much that's relevant. I would look further into android styles and how they work.

As to how to fix it, I would look [here](http://www.androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=3307).

Answer (score 0):

Add a view with other color between buttons.
Or choice a picture that not fill button as a background.
The reason that makes buttons very close is that you use a color as a background,then,the color will fill your button widget if without margin.